# Writing an expression to recursively extract data between parenthesis

Tags: php, regex, recursion, tokenize

I'm trying to write a regular expression to split a string into separate elements inside matching curly braces. First off, it needs to be recursive, and second off, it has to return the offsets (like with `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`).

I actually think this is probably a less efficient way to process this data, but I'm unsure of an easier, more performance driven technique. (If you've got one, I would love to hear it!)

So, the input can be in this format:

```
Hello {#name}! I'm a {%string|sentence|bit of {#random} text}
```

Processing the data is easy enough if it's in *this* format:

```
Hello {#name}! I'm a {%string|sentence|bit of random text}
```

But it's the recursive curly braces within another set of curly braces that is the problem when it comes to processing.
I'm using the following code to split the string:

```
preg_match_all("/(?<={)[^}]*(?=})/m", $string, $braces, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

And as before mentioned, it's very nice for the simple form. Just less so for the more complicated form. The intention for this (and I have it functional in a non-recursive form) is to replace each parenthesized area with the content as processed by functions, working upwards.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to write `Hello {#name}! I'm a {%string|sentence|bit of {?(random == "strange") ? {#random} : "strange"}} text}` and for it to be manageable.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: So, for `Hello {#name}! I'm a {%string|sentence|bit of {#random} text}`, you need to capture `{#name}`, `{%string|sentence|bit of {#random} text}`, and `{#random}`?

Comment: Exactly. And I need to ideally capture the positions, too! Though I still think there has to be a better way to do this, this takes a while in very long strings.

Comment: If your goal is to replace each parenthesis, using a recursive pattern will not be useful. What you need is to replace the innermost parenthesis until there are no more parenthesis in your string.

Comment: @casimir-et-hippolyte That makes sense, but I'm not sure how I'd implement that. Do you know any resources that could help?

Comment: The main problem of the lookahead trick is that it doesn't consume characters, so you can't use it with `preg_replace`. A way consists to target innermost parenthesis and to use `preg_replace_callback` in a while loop. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457853/how-to-implement-template-with-conditions-with-preg-replace/28461255#28461255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage PCRE regex power of capturing groups in look-aheads and subroutines to get the nested `{...}` substrings.

A [regex demo is available here](https://regex101.com/r/mF3aD4/1).

```
$re = "#(?=(\{(?>[^{}]|(?1))*+\}))#"; 
$str = "Hello {#name}! I'm a {%string|sentence|bit of {#random} text}"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/i5yocJ)

It will return an array with the captured {...}-like strings and their positions:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {#name}
            [1] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => {%string|sentence|bit of {#random} text}
            [1] => 21
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => {#random}
            [1] => 46
        )

)
```

Comment: That solves my problem. Is there a method that would also be supported with JavaScript, perhaps? I'm working on this with PHP, but I will want to port it at some point to JavaScript.

Comment: In JavaScript, there is no support for subroutines in regex. That means, you won't be able to match nested curly braces with regex there.

Comment: I'm assuming my only option for that will be some form of parser/lexer or something?

Comment: Yes, a kind of a state machine. You might find some great tips in the [Matching Nested Constructs in JavaScript article at Flagrant Badassery](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-match-nested) blog.

Comment: I'll take a look at that. But in the meantime I'll get it all working PHP-side.